# Display the searched characters with coloring [Laravel10]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display the searched characters with yellow coloring.

I searched web and Here is my current code.

I'm trying to display the searched characters with yellow coloring.

I searched web and Here is my current code.

I can search keywords and get result.

but colors function are not working.

I'm guessing the code of blade? but not sure.
Could you teach me what is causing please?

**Blade**

```php
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<tr>                           
    <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>                            
    <td>{{ $result }}</td
<tr>    
@endforeach
```

**Controller **

```php
$keyword = $request->input('search'); 
    $q = Post::query();     
  
    if(isset($request->keyword) && $request->keyword_type === "or"){
        $keywords = explode(",", $request->keyword);
        $q->where(function ($query) use($keywords) {
            foreach($keywords as $keyword){
                $query->orWhere('title', 'LIKE',"%$keyword%");
            }
        });
    } elseif(isset($request->keyword)) {
        $keywords = explode(",", $request->keyword);
        foreach($keywords as $keyword){
            $q->where('title', 'LIKE',"%$keyword%");
        }
    }

        // \DB::enableQueryLog();
        $results = $q->get();
        // dd(\DB::getQueryLog());

        $results->count=count($results);

    // Highlisght strings area 
        if(isset($request->keyword)) {
            foreach($results as $result){
                $keywords = explode(",", $request->keyword);
                $result->title = $this->search_text_highlight($keywords, $result->title);
            }
        }
        $results->count=count($results);

    $count_result = count($posts);
  


    return view('posts.index')
    ->with([
        'posts' => $posts,         
        'result' => $result->title  
    ])->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    
}

/**
 * function find keyword if finds make it yellow highlight 
 *
 * @param array $keywords 
 * @param string $target_string 
 * @return string $target_string
 */
public function search_text_highlight($keywords, $target_string)
{
    // if target is empty return the string 
    if(empty($keywords)){
        return $target_string;
    }

    foreach($keywords as $keyword){
        // if find keyword highlight and return 
        if( ($pos = mb_strpos($target_string, $keyword, 0, 'UTF-8')) !== false ){
            // get keyword from text 
            $str = mb_substr($target_string, $pos, mb_strlen($keyword, 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8');
            // make yellow highlight color 
            $target_string = str_replace($str, "<span style='background-color:yellow'>{$str}</span>", $target_string);
        }
    }
    return $target_string;
}
```

Comment: 'result' => $result->title   , when you pass it like this,  it will only get last value not all values within the loop, it is overwritten by last value only.. You need to use array instead

Comment: @Akshay ak Thank you for answering me. I see. but I'm not sure how to handle this. Could you teach me writing please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 $results = $q->get();

    $highlightedResults = [];
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $keywords = explode(",", $request->keyword);
        $highlightedTitle = $this->search_text_highlight($keywords, $result->title);
        $highlightedResults[] = [
            'post' => $result,
            'highlightedTitle' => $highlightedTitle,
        ];
    }

    return view('posts.index', [
        'highlightedResults' => $highlightedResults,
    ])->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
```

Blade file

```
@foreach ($highlightedResults as $highlightedResult)
    <div>
        <h2>{{ $highlightedResult['highlightedTitle'] }}</h2>
        <p>{{ $highlightedResult['post']->tag }}</p>
        <p>{{ $highlightedResult['post']->description }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @dear Akshay ak Thank you very much for code.
I tried your code. but I can't display result.
I adjust blade code. sometime Undefined variable sometimes are no error but I can't display yellow marked sentence. Could you teach me blade code again?  my original code was  @ foreach ($posts as $post) {{ $post->title }} {{ $post->tag }}  {{ $post->description }} @ endforeach and I could get all data sucessfully.

Comment: Yes i have edited the code , please check

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I had to adjust little. like this {!! $highlightedResult['highlightedTitle'] !!} it was not yellow color showing and { } this Curly braces  appear. Everything working perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<tr>                           
    <td>{!! $post->title !!}</td>                            
    <td>{!! $result !!}</td
<tr>    
@endforeach
```

try with this code. Make sure to use {!! $result !!} instead of {{ $result }} to render the HTML as it is, allowing the  tags for highlighting to take effect.

Comment: Dear @Javad Geravand Thank you for answering me.
I tired your blade code. Thank you! but still I can't get result with yellow color. 

I'm guessing this controller is something wrong. I'm getting worried am I get right value 'result'. Could you please take a look this too?

Comment: because you passed like this :

`return view('posts.index')
    ->with([
        'posts' => $posts,         
        'result' => $result->title  
    ])->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);`

Comment: you should pass them in compact like this:

`$posts = Post:all()
$result =  // everythings tou nedd
return view('posts.index',compact('posts','result'));`

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I rewrite controller code as you post. but I still having problem. about, 'result' and 'results' .  I can't receive data correctly. I'm not sure about this line $result->title = $this->search_text_highlight($keywords, $result->title); If I write blade code like you post.  Undefined variable error $result appears.  I can get search anwer  as $post->title and $post->description. but I can't get as $ result and $results.